# Flex-box - how to fill the "entire" space preserving item proportions?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Code first: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sGwgf

HTML:

```
<container>
  <item>first</item>
  <item>second</item>
  <item>third</item>
</container>
```

CSS:

```
container{
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

item{
  flex: 1; //so each item should be the same size, am I right?
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

Now how it looks at different container sizes:
1:

[image]

2:

[image]
How to force that third item to be equal size as the first two?
Can I achieve that by using flexbox?

3:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want those items to be on the same line for #2, you need to update your `flex-wrap` value:

```
 -webkit-flex-flow: no-wrap;
```

If you want layout #3 to continue be effected at some resolutions, you should simply use a media query:

```
 @media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  container{
    -webkit-flex-flow: wrap;
   }
  }
```

Note: `container` isn't an HTML5 element, you should ensure your markup is valid: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: as far as I know, I can use custom tags in HTML5:)

Comment: Your markup will be invalid if you do. You can use custom `data-*` attributes, but HTML5 specification defines what is a valid element.

Comment: Well... OK, but if my code becomes much more clear and it works in every modern browser (specification explicitly instruct browser vendors to treat "unknown" elements as inline, unstyled tags) - I don't care about markup :) I'm sure it will become more common over time. For me, custom tags are as handy as SASS.

Comment: Please read this: http://validator.w3.org/docs/why.html I would never hire a web developer that cowboys their markup, and I doubt many other professional web shops would either.